# Copy data from datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, copy-paste

I am trying to copy data from a datagrid to an Excel file.

My ClipboardCopyMode is set to 'IncludeHeader'. If I copy & paste multiple rows, the headers show up, but the rows are all empty (no data?). For example if I copy 3 rows and paste it in Excel, it looks like the following:

```
 Header1    Header2    Header3    Header4
.
.
.
```

(Of course not with the periods, but they are indicating the rows.)

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using DataBinding you have to use on your DataGridTemplateColumn

```
ClipboardContentBinding
```

to specify which property do you want to copy.

Comment: Thanx, I do indeed use DataGridTemplateColumns.